# Update Specific Rows via Scraped Data on Python \ Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python/Django, so please bear with me! I've read all the other threads but I still don't get it done. I have a django framework blog having a user pages that user can create and follow item prices. My client can be create new item and follow prices and stock status.

client_table:

```
ID  ITEMNO  PRICE
1   TMEP       
2   TMEP       
3   TMEP       
4   TTVP       
5   TMEP       
6   TTVP
```

Thos rows goes on 1000+ now and as you can see a lot of my client following same items. I have an also a little bs4 engine that scrape prices on api and save in another table.

scraped_data_table :

```
ID  ITEMNO  PRICE 
1   TMEP    78,5€   
2   TTVP    112,00€
```

mybs4:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self,  *args, **options):)
        html = urlopen('')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        site=json.loads(soup.text)

        for i in range(len(site)):
            price = site[i]['priceeu']

            try:
                Job.objects.create(
                    price=price,

                )
                print('%s added' % (price,))
            except Exception as e: print(e)
        self.stdout.write( 'Well Done' )
```

I'd try to change try method like **Job.objects.update** and write on client_table but didnt figure out.

client_table after scraped prices.

```
ID  ITEMNO  PRICE
1   TMEP    78,5   
2   TMEP    78,5   
3   TMEP    78,5   
4   TTVP    78,5   
5   TMEP    78,5   
6   TTVP    78,5
```

I have to seek help here as a last resort. I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Clarification. You want to update `client_table` with the prices for `itemno` instead of saving it to `Jobs`?

Comment: Exactly!  They are in different tables but in same db <3

Comment: Try this: `client_table.objects.filter(ITEMNO='TMEP').update(price=price)`